# redux package not installed correctly

Tags: redux, react-redux

I installed redux as a package but I get this error:

```
export 'default' (imported as 'Redux') was not found in 'redux' (possible exports: __DO_NOT_USE__ActionTypes, applyMiddleware, bindActionCreators, combineReducers, compose, createStore)
```

take a look at the repo:
https://github.com/Mai9550/redux-course

Answer (score 1):

The error message is correct - there is no default export from the `redux` package, so your import statement needs to change.

The recommended pattern is using the actual named imports:

```js
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
```

You *could* use the "combine all named imports into an object" import pattern:

```js
import * as Redux from 'redux';
```

However, and this is more important: **you shouldn't be using the `redux` package by itself**.  Instead, today **you *should* be using our official Redux Toolkit package** instead to write your Redux logic.

Please see our Redux core docs tutorials, which explain how to learn and use Redux the right way:

https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index